# Envio de imagem com phpmailer

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Tenho um site que o fomulário precisa ser autenticado,estou usando a biblioteca phpmailer, até aí tudo bem eu consegui, no entanto esse formulário tem uma foto que deve ser enviada junto e não estou conseguindo fazer com que essa imagem chegue na caixa de entrada.
usei vários exemplos que ni na internet, como este `$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['arquivo']);` mas não funcionou :/

Comment: tente ser mais especifico qual errou apareceu ?

Comment: Apareceu este erro Fatal error: Call to a member function AddAttachment() on a non-object in /home/sindesep/public_html/teste1/enviar.php on line 29

Answer (score -1):

Tente trocar para `$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'])`.

Não sei ao certo como o método *addAttachment* funciona, mas acho que ele não foi preparado para ler a chave `tmp_name` sozinho.

Comment: eu ja usei esse código,  o email é enviado mas não chega a foto anexada